# Why "R Graphic: Device" window in Windows when opened in a children process of Node Webkit open, show plots but keep not responding?

Tags: r, windows, node.js, node-webkit

When I open a "R Graphic: Device" in a children process of Node Webkit in Windows, the window keep not responding but show plots. In Linux (Fedora), it works normally.

My code:

```
if(version == "0.0.0"){
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
          ls  = spawn('R', ['--no-save','--no-restore', '-q']);
}else{
    spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        ls  = spawn(process.env.comspec, ['/c', 'C:/"Program Files"/R/R-3.1.2/bin/x64/R.exe', '--no-save','--no-restore', '-q']);
}
```

This part is where I open the child_process. Version "0.0.0" is Linux and Version "0.0.1" is Windows. To open a "R Graphic" window I send "win.graph()" or "x11()" to the R children process through Node WebKit.

It seems that something is sending many commands because you can't move the window. After same time you can but it keep not responding but showing plots.

How can I fix that? or is there another way to show on the fly plots?